# use of the word 'vanity'

Tags: word-choice

[image]

Does this show a rare use of the word 'vanity'? Is this an old-fashioned word? While reading I find this word 'vanity' in old literature books, so can we deduce that it is not much common now, thus 'pride' can be a better alternative as far as modern language is concerned?

Comment: Could you provide the context you want to use the word? To me pride and vanity are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a good use of Google Ngrams. For starters, this graph conflates multiple unrelated senses and uses of *pride* (e.g. a group of lions, a young horse's energy) and *vanity* (e.g. a type of cosmetic case, a table for applying makeup and jewelry). Second, the commonality of a word or lack thereof is not necessarily related to its obsolescence. The word *thou* appears 2790 in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (COCA). The word *iPad* appears 2230 times. Third, there are weaknesses in the Google Books index and its use in general. That collection is not a consistent representation of written English over time, besides omitting spoken English of course.

As katatahito notes in a comment, *vanity* and *pride* are not interchangeable, and how they are used is also different. As for connotations, *pride* is relatively neutral — *taking pride in your work* is a positive sentiment, *letting pride stand in the way of reconciliation* is negative — whereas *vanity* in the sense of conceit is usually negative. *Vanity* is arguably one variation of pride, or a degree of it.

*Vanity* appears in a list of spelling words for [5th-graders](https://www.learnthat.org/word_lists/view/3067), so I wouldn't rate it as particularly difficult or obscure. If you want to go by prevalence, *vanity* is far from rare. There are 3448 instances in COCA; by comparison, *popcorn* has only 3222.